# How to display images of child products in woocommerce group product?

Tags: woocommerce

Recently I was designing in wordpress with woocommerce. While creating group products I wanted to display images of child products too. I checked on "catalog visibility" too but only name appears.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer, add this to wherever you want to display an image:

```
<?php $img_url = $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
<img src="<?php  echo $image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
```